# I am Not able to bind Range picker Value with asp Net Core Model

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor-pages

> I have used bootstrap date range picker in my Asp Net Core Project .
> And I want to Bind value with my Model but I am not able to do it .

**This is my Code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="date">Start Date*</label>
<input type="text" asp-for="date" name="datefilter"  />
<div class="invalid-feedback">
Please Select Start Date.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**This is my jQuery Code for Date Range Picker :**

```
$(function () {

            $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
                autoUpdateInput: false,
                locale: {
                    cancelLabel: 'Clear'
                }
            });

            $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
            });

            $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $(this).val('');
            });
        });
```

**This is My Model with which I want to bind this date range picker value:**

```
public string date { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @Coder,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: @Rena No, I Don't want to do this Using AJAX I want to do when clicking on the Submit button While posting Data.

Comment: Hi @Coder,please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Rena What should be type of date variable if I want to do this ?

Comment: It should be string like what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why you could not get the string value is because the input name `datefilter` does not match the model property name.

You need read how does model binding system work first:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#complex-types

Here is a working demo you could refer to:

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model TestModel
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Test">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="date">Start Date*</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="date" name="date" />
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please Select Start Date.
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('input[name="date"]').daterangepicker({
                autoUpdateInput: false,
                locale: {
                    cancelLabel: 'Clear'
                }
            });
            $('input[name="date"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
                var data = {
                    date: picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY')
                };
            });

            $('input[name="date"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $(this).val('');
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Test(TestModel test)
{
    //do your stuff...
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Of course.I have changed my code.Check the razor view,I change the name of the input and do not forget to changing the jquery.You could receive a date range string which is in your model in the action.